# What is the default value of uninitialized member bool varaible in C++?

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Bool_tester {
    private:
        bool flag;
    public:
        bool get()
        {
            return flag;
        }

};

int main()
{
    // Create an instance of Bool_tester
    Bool_tester test1;

    // Call the get member function
    cout << test1.get() << endl;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Its output is 204 and true. Is the default value of Boolean member variable true?

Comment: There is none. The value is *indeterminate* if not initialized or assigned (directly or indirectly).  Static linkage will give you a default value of `false`, as will value-initialization, neither of which you have here. Unrelated i'm curious how *both* `204` and `true` are output in *this* program.

Comment: I tested many times . but  Its output is  is true . and the value stored is 204

Comment: Test it all you want; but you're observations are witness to *undefined behavior*. You're evaluating indeterminate data and draw the conclusion that, because it appears repetitive, the behavior you're witnessing must be defined. In short, you're confusing *defined* behavior with *observed* behavior. The former, if present, can reliably determine the latter; The reverse is *not* the case.

Comment: *Output* of the program is true (and return code 0), and you see value 204 with debugger I suppose. Booleans are still integers in the computer (they could be stored with 1 bit, but usually an entire memory location is used). Non-zero means true, so 204 is true. This is undefined behavior, though. For example changing optimization settings or debug/release setting often change behavior of programs which have undefined behavior. Also phase of the moon might have an effect, in some cases.

Comment: Seeing an apparently constant value *might* simply mean that the memory location of the boolean variable used for loading the program and is written to already *before* `main` is called. But that has nothing to do with the code you have written and might change with changing compiler settings or even on OS update without changing the programme at all...

Comment: On a related note: since it's undefined, it's possible that both `test1.get() == true` and `test1.get() == false` are false.

Comment: @WhozCraig undefined behaviour is undefined

Comment: If you wonder how that (@molbdnilo's comment) could happen *technically*: Compiler might spot undefined behaviour and just optimise away both if and else branches of the code (which is totally legal on UB occurring), so neither `if(condition)` nor `else` are entered and thus neither `condition` nor `!condition` applies...

Comment: Please don't edit your post to ask a completely unrelated question after you received an answer. This is considered vandalizing, and invalidates the efforts people put into answering the original question. Instead of doing that, ask a new question.

Comment: I have ban on questions . I can only edit previous questions

Comment: @Hamza Doing so will only attract downvotes, putting you even deeper into the question ban. I doubt you'll get answers this way. Instead, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) on how to lift the ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only global variables get the default value of zero if they are not explicitly initialized.

For local variables it's not required for the compiler to clean up the content of the memory they are assigned to.

If any local variables are given a non-zero garbage value, which would evaluate to true in a Boolean variable, this is what happens in your case. Primitive data types that are not initialized have any values, and good practice is to initialize the local variable.

Answer (score 1):

My compiler emits a warning:

```
main.cpp:48:27: warning: 'test1' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

So you see not the default value, but any value which was before in the memory at the address your bool value is now in place.

For non-class types you can use [zero-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization%22zero-initialization%22) to get your values initialized, which means for boolean it is initialized to `false`.

```
class Bool_tester {
    bool flag{};
    ...
}
```

Comment: *"If you want to have default initialization"* - careful with your terms. What you show isn't default initialization; it's *value initialization* of a member, covered in  § 8.5.8.4 [dcl.init] of the standard. The OP's problem is actually because default initialization was all that was done, which, per § 8.5.7.3, falls into the "no initialization is performed" bucket, and leading to the indeterminate problem in the first place.

Comment: @WhozCraig: If I have "value initialization" without giving a value, I expected to get "default  initialization". What is the correct wording to have value initialization to default value? I will correct my answer if you can help to find the correct wording. Thanks!

Comment: Value initialization with an empty initializer (eg. `()` or `{}`) will regress to *zero-initialization* for non-class types (in this case, a `bool`). In short, for your code, `flag` is value-initialized without arguments, hence zero-initialized, hence definitively *false*. In the OP's code, `flag` was default-initialized, and for non-class types, that means no initialization is performed, hence indeterminate. Your code is correct, it just needed a better description of what was happening.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I'm in hope to fixed it correctly. Can you check again ;) Thanks for your advice!

Comment: The value is unspecified and a program that reads it has undefined behaviour. You cannot promise it is "any value which was before in the memory at the address your bool value is now in place". It is impossible to rationalise about the program.